# Get a large area landsat 8 metadata from earth-engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, metadata, landsat-8

Obviously the code below will returned null because there's no picture in landsat 8 will contain such a large area.

```
#python
geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[73.0, 25.0],
      [73.0, 49.0],
      [125.0, 25.0],
      [125.0,49.0]])
landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA').filterDate(date_start, data_end).filterBounds(geometry)
```

But I wonder is there any way that can get a Collection contains pictures which can cover the whole area. I'd prefer these pictures are all metadata **before mosaic**. Mosaic() make no sense because I want to do some pre-process on single picture.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please include the code of what you have tried so far, which helps us help you. Please also include what you specifically mean by "black margin in metadata" and what metadata you are trying to access in an ImageCollection for the American continent.